# Amazon AWS Nat Gateway high usage

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have had a Linux instance running for years and the typical bill looks like this with 744 hours of the Linux instance and a much smaller number for the Nat Gateway:

| Description | Units | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $0.045 per NAT Gateway Hour | 81.000 Hrs | $3.65 |
| $0.0464 per On Demand Linux t2.medium Instance Hour | 744.000 Hrs | $34.52 |

Only recently has the Nat Gateway jumped up to be the same 744 hours:

| Description | Units | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $0.045 per NAT Gateway Hour | 744.000 Hrs | $33.48 |
| $0.0464 per On Demand Linux t2.medium Instance Hour | 744.000 Hrs | $34.52 |

I am not exactly sure what has caused this. I have done more FTP and SSH to the server than usual, but just wondering specifically what can cause such a big increase?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the amount of network traffic you sent through the NAT Gateway. If you weren't seeing 744 hours on the NAT gateway before, then you didn't have a NAT Gateway provisioned for the entire month previously.

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid now. I now remember I started to play around with creating a blockchain ethereum network in this account. I ended up doing my testing in another account, but I forgot I did some very initial tests in this account where I set up a VPC and forgot to delete it.

Comment: It shows on your billing clearly.

Answer (score 2):

One month is roughly 750 hours. If you only got billed for 81 hours, then you were only using the gateway for part of the month.

**Update in response to comment**

> My question is what could have caused my Nat Gateway usage to make such a big jump to 744 hours in the last month?

You had it running for the entire month.

Whereas the other billing entry -- which you have edited out of your question -- showed it running for only part of the month (81 hours).

Perhaps a better question would be "why was it only running for 81 hours when I thought it was running for the entire month?"

Comment: I updated my question with other info. I have a Linux instance that I have had running for many years 24/7 and is always 744 hours and until now, the Nat Gateway has always been just a fraction of that. My question is what could have caused my Nat Gateway usage to make such a big jump to 744 hours in the last month?

Comment: @Primico please format these numbers as a table like I've done with the earlier ones - it's basically impossible to read them otherwise.

Comment: @Primico - the only answer that I have is that you were not running the NAT Gateway when you thought you were. 744 hours is what you should expect to pay per month.